# how add elements in collection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to learn databases, specially mongoDb.

I use Mongoose and i try to add elements in my collection. I know that's a basic question but i don't understand where can be my problem

there is my code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/hackathon", (error)=>{
    if (!error){
        console.log("YESSS")
    }
    else {
        console.log("rip")
    }
    var friend = { firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'Potter' };
    
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
    });

});
```

the mongoose.connect function correctly, and the console.log gives me

```
 { name: 'mycol',
    type: 'collection',
```

I tried to do :

collection.push  but he doesn't know it.
i tried something like that

```
 var dbo = db.db("mycol");

    dbo.collection("mycol").insertOne(friend, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        db.close();
      });
```

(i found it on stack overflow but that do nothing)
Is there something i miss?

I think it's an easy thing and i just miss something in my comprehension.

Sorry for my english and thanks !

Comment: Well, that should work, how do you check whether it works or not?

Comment: so the name of the collection is `mycol` or `customers`? it seems like you're accessing the collection `customers` of a `mycol` named db in your code...

Comment: Hello, i  use the cosole.log to check the number of elements

Comment: the name is my col, sorry i tapped wrong, i think the problem is on

var dbo = db.db("mycol");

    dbo.collection("mycol").insertOn

i use 2 times (mycol)*

Answer (score 0):

I used an other technique, i don't know if its the best solution so i created a schema (with differents elements, name, number-phone etc), and with a new and save, i found my solution.

Thanks for your answers